# Can I post files from one server to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a simple node server to store files using express-fileupload.And I found that the files stored in the server will be deleted when the website is updated.Therefore I've made another server for storing files.Here's some of the source code.

Uploadfile.com

```js
//...someting
var file=req.files.fle
  file.mv(path.join(__dirname+"/cloud/",file.name),(err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.send("ERROR")
      }else{
//something..
```

Is there any ways that I can send the file to the website that used to store file(for example,StoreFile.com) by changing the __dirname?
Please provide sample source code thx.

Comment: yes, you can send files from one server to another *Here's some of the source code.* - what does that do? is it browser code? server 1 code? server 2 code?

Comment: It's the express code of the server used to upload files

Comment: you say `I've made another website for storing files` - is it a website? or just a server with an API to accept files you send to it?

Comment: Sorry for not clear,its a server with API.

Comment: well, then you should be able to do what you want- without seeing how your two servers communicate, I assume you're not having an issue in that regard